# S2S VPN between on premise through pfsense for azure to application VM in azure

Tags: pfsense, site-to-site-vpn

I am trying to create multi S2S ipsec VPN connections between on premise locations and a "pfsense for azure" VM. In the same subnet, I also have a application VM running. I can create a VPN tunnel no problem between my on premise device (meraki MX64 and the pfsense box), but I am unable to route traffic through to my Azure application VM. The pfsense VM only has 1 interface (called WAN). I am unable to ping or get traffic through from on premise to my application VM and visa versa. Can someone help me please?